# From WSJ, my number is 136

Tags: elementary-number-theory

My Number is $136$

> Ana and Boris play a logic game. They both know that possibly identical positive integers, $a$ and $b$, are chosen by a third party. Their product is written on Ana’s forehead and their sum is written on Boris’s forehead. Each can see the other’s number but not his or her own. After each sees the number on the other’s forehead, one says to the other, “There is no way you can know your number.” The other responds, “I now know my number is $136$.”

According to the WSJ, here is the putative solution.

My Number is $136$ answer explained:

$a = 1$ and $b = 135$. Ana sees $136$ on Boris and knows whatever product Boris sees $(1 \times 135,\ 2 \times 134,\ 3 \times 133$,\ etc.), he can’t know his number. Boris sees $135$ on Ana and considers he may have $3 + 45 (= 47 + 1),\ 5 + 27 (= 31 + 1),\ 9 + 15 (= 23 + 1)$, or $1 + 135$. The first three possibilities are eliminated by adding to one more than a prime (which would disallow Ana from making her statement) so Boris deduces his number is $136$.

**I THINK THERE IS AN ERROR IN THE LOGIC OF THE ANSWER**.

Clearly we are to assume that both Ana and Boris are both math whizzes and that Ana, too, could deduce that if $135$ happens to be written on her forehead, then Boris can deduce that $136$ is written on his forehead. So she simply cannot make the claim that "whatever product Boris sees, he can't know his number."

It would seem that the problem could be much better posed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ be the number that Boris sees on Ana's forehead : as long as $A$ is not prime, it can be written as the product of two smaller numbers $x$ and $y$, which would give Boris a sum of $x+y$, but also as the product of $1$ and $A$, which would give Boris the (different) sum $1+A$. So the only way Boris could find the correct sum on his forehead would be if $A$ is prime, and then this number would be $A+1$. Since Ana can see that $136=135+1$ but $135$ is not a prime, she knows that Boris cannot know the number.

Comment: If the number on Anna's forehead is $655=665\cdot 1=131\cdot 5$, then how would Boris know whether the number on his forehead is $656=655+1$ or $136=131+5$?

Comment: I think Ana's claim is that Boris cannot know his number *without additional information*. That he is able to guess it using the additional information she just provided does not contradict her claim. But I agree that's less clear.

Comment: In essence I agree. But the problem would have been better stated if instead of Ana declaring that there is no way Boris could know, she said: "Most likely you can't know the number on your forehead but I can see a way that you might." That would be delightful because it leaves Boris wondering whether Ana thinks he's smart enough to figure out that one way and teases the reader to figure it out, just as you have. Again, thank you for your insights on this problem.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is unsound. Boris could easily know his number if Ana's number were 4183, 3103, or some others, so her original statement is incorrect. If the numbers were limited to 3 digit numbers it would work